# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using python 3.6 on my pc(windows 10)
I wanted to install tensor flow package (using pip),
SO opened the cmd and typed the following as specified in the tensorflow website,
**i want to install the cpu package not the gpu package**

C:\Users\rahul>C:\Windows.old\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\ **pip3.exe install --upgrade tensorflow**

but i get this error

**Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow**,
How do i overcome this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a 64 bit version of Python.